# Error "The term 'unblock-file' is not recognized"

Tags: flutter, dart

See this image and errors:

[image: img]

Please solve this error `The term 'unblock-file is not recognized`, it shows many errors. I browsed too much for it but I couldn't find a single answer working for me!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is saying that a file called `Unblock-file.exe` is missing.

Have a look here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-7#:~:text=The%20Unblock%2DFile%20cmdlet%20lets,the%20computer%20from%20untrusted%20files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-7#:%7E:text=The%20Unblock%2DFile%20cmdlet%20lets,the%20computer%20from%20untrusted%20files).

Updating Windows would fix this.  (By the way, Windows 7 is outdated now.)
You can try Linux (if on low ram) or Windows 10.